# Gradient Estimate for Manifold with Boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

The standard gradient estimate states that:

Let $M$ be n-dimensional complete manifold with $Ric\geq -(n-1)k, k\geq 0$. If $u$ is a positive harmonic function on $M$, then in any geodesic ball $B_a(x)$,we have $\frac{\|u\|}{u}\leq C_n(\frac{1+ak^{\frac{1}{2}}}{a})$ for $x\in B_{a/2}(x)$.

My question is, if $M$ is a manifold with boundary, $Ric\geq -(n-1)k$ and second fundamental form $II \geq \lambda$, do we still have similar result?

Thanks in advance for anyone who could offer help.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't this an interior estimate? So if $a \not \in \partial M$ shouldn't the same result hold for a manifold with boundary (independent of the assumption on the 2nd ff) provided that $r< \mathrm{dist}_g (a, \partial M)$.

Comment: Or are you interested in the case $a \in \partial M$?

Comment: Yes. The maximal might be achieved at boundary.

Comment: I got the answer and it's not true. We can construct functions on the boundary so that  $\frac{\nabla_{\Sigma} u}{u}$ is arbitrary large, and extend it to a harmonic function.